# Recommendations for a Wireless-N USB dongle?

Tags: 10.04, hardware, usb, wireless

Please advise which wireless-N usb adapters should work seamlessly with Ubuntu 10.04. I have tried SMC and Linksys, but they all need to have drivers compiled for them.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good question, and the wiki page most people mention ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)  is outdated and user-submitted information that is sometimes incorrect, it seems.

These pages are a good place to start, although they are probably more helpful if you have the lspci info to hand. (Previous experience shows that some cards with the same model name contain different chipsets!)

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/FAQ

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices/USB

I am also on the lookout for a similar card, and would like to hear personal recommendation including from an ubuntu expert with a USB wireless-n device working flawlessly out of the box (and at n-speeds rather than g-speeds) in 10.04 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Intel's Wireless-N is good and out-of-the box (at least my Mini PCI-express one) Intel also have a good reputation for drivers (mostly) in Linux.

Comment: true but do they make usb dongles too?

Answer (score 1):

I use some of the D-Link N adapters. If I remember correctly, the DWA-130 works out-of-the box, while the DWA-160 would require a simple install of this ndiswrapper software to use the Windows driver. But they both seem to work well.

Answer (score 0):

That is the only way around. Currently I am using the same method on Windows drivers with Linksys PCI N Adapter and I am just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://linuxplained.com/linux-compatible-usb-wireless-adapters-2012/) identifies 5 which are said to work in Linux. I haven't tested any, but may report back when I do.

Answer (score 0):

I use an ASUS USB N-13 dongle.It does not work right out the box but you can Google instructions on how to make it work.I takes less than 5 minutes.Mine has working flawlessly for years now!Here's a link with the instructions on how to make the dongle work with Lucid.http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499153

Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Provide possibly an abridged version of the content here to help create a higher quality answer